# How to extact all value instance of a model in django views.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hy Guys, I have a question for you. I have the following model:

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField

class Totale_Vendite(models.Model):
    totale_vendite = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_dalle_vendite = models.CharField(max_length=100, editable=True)
    ricavi_01 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_02 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_03 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_04 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_05 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_06 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_07 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_08 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_09 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_10 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_11 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
    ricavi_12 = MoneyField(decimal_places=2,default=0, default_currency='EUR',max_digits=11)
```

Each instance rappresents the income on the month utilizing the djmoney app. In my views.py I want to extract for each instance ( ricavi_01, ricavi_02) the "amount" value (not currency). For the moment I have tried only the following way, that is to extract the value individually for each month:

```
def ricavi_dalle_vendite(request):
    queryset = Totale_Vendite.objects.all()
    labels = ['Gen','Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mag', 'Giu', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Ott', 'Nov', 'Dic']
    data = []

    for entry in queryset:
        data.append(str(entry.ricavi_01.amount))
....
```

how could solve it following the DRY principles???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target is to only get the list of `Totale_Vendite` entries with `ricavi_01` field money amount (without currency), the you can simply do this:

```
data = queryset.values_list('ricavi_01', flat=True)
```

This will produce the items list of decimal type.

Comment: Thanks Charnel, but I want to have, in "data", all instances value of the model Totale_Vendite (not only ricavi_01, but also ricavi_02, ricavi_03 etc.). How can do it in my for circle?

Comment: Just add thous fields, separated by comma, to `value` method call and remove `flat=True` argument.

Comment: this method does not work. I try `data = queryset.values_list('ricavi_01', 'ricavi_02')`

Comment: Does not work becouse If I try to plot the result of "data" don't display anything. If I use `for entry in queryset:
    #    data.append(str(entry.ricavi_01.amount))` it display the chart and the value